# Is there any official documentation of JavaMail which states the support of TLSv1.2?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, tls1.2

I landed on following exception while using mail-1.4 jar in an java application to send mail:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls [PN1PR01CA0107.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

To resolve above exception, I tried various versions of JavaMail. I could resolve my issue with the help of javax.mail-1.5.3 jar.

My query is there any supporting official documentation or blog which states to upgrade the JavaMail jar to version 1.5.3 or above?

Comment: What you want to update to is [Jakarta Mail 1.x](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this depends on the TLS versions supported by the Java version you use, and not on JavaMail itself (I might be wrong though). So, which **exact** Java version are you using?

Comment: Also, which exact JavaMail version are you using? Is it literally 1.4.0? Also, it might be overridable through property `mail.<protocol>.ssl.protocols` (e.g. `mail.imap.ssl.protocols`)

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, okay, got your point. well,I m using java-11.0.03.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Jakarta Mail changes list](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/CHANGES.txt) (it lists changes including original SUN versions) does not mention TLS version support. But I do not think it should.  That should be left to the TLS runtime that it is using as backend.